# How to show a validation failure message in only a single cell of Bootstrap Vue table?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am building a `Bootstrap Vue` based datatable using [this](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table) component.

I have multiple text fields on each row of this table. What I am trying to do is add a validation state to these text fields based on some event. But I am getting clueless about how can I only target a particular row to show a validation failure error message.

My code snippet below, I'm using `scoped slot`:

```
           <template v-slot:cell(account_id)="data">
                <div @mousedown="itemBeingModified = data" @focusin="itemBeingModified = data">
                    <b-form-input
                        trim
                        v-model="data.value"
                        @update="handleAccountIDChange"
                        id="data.index"
                        :state=false
                    >
                    </b-form-input>

                    <!-- This will only be shown if the preceding input has an invalid state -->
                    <b-form-invalid-feedback id="input-live-feedback">
                        Value required
                    </b-form-invalid-feedback>
                </div>
            </template>
```

And below is my table snippet which shows validation failure getting applied to cells from all the rows:

[image]

How can I target only a single row for displaying validation failure error message?

Answer (score 1):

I would check for an error to the data.value property.
To explain better, I see you are using data.value as v-model here:

```
                <b-form-input
                    trim
                    v-model="data.value"
                    @update="handleAccountIDChange"
                    id="data.index"
                    :state=false
                >
```

So I would do something like:

```
                <!-- This will only be shown if the preceding input has an invalid state -->
                <b-form-invalid-feedback id="input-live-feedback" v-if="!isValid(data.value)">
                    Value required
                </b-form-invalid-feedback>
```

and in your methods:

```
    isValid(value)
   {
       //your logic here
       return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Raffobaffo, but I am trying to show/hide validation message based on some event / activity outside of this cell (e.g. based on some value in adjacent cell). How to do that?

Comment: Depends a lot from the logic you'll want to use, but I would actually modify the array elements based on the events/activity, and then use the modified value like this: 
v-if="! data.isValid". Do not forget to use Vue.set on the objects to make the new property reactive. Eg. say you want to set isValid on an object that did not have this property. You would use Vue.set(objectName,'isValid',false)